# custom dhcp client on windows -manualy send discover and request packets?

Tags: windows, networking, dhcp

My ISP has lease time 1 minute on its wifi connection. It basicly means that my system constatntly resets interface while setting same IP over and over on IP. When I set IP, gateway, netmask manualy then I can achive 10-30 minutes of perfect connection however if I don't ask (discover,request) dhcp for IP it soon will asign it to someone else.

I need dhcp client for windows that is not windows build in dhcp client. I need to send disover, request dhcp packets via commandline. I did not found ANY dhcp clients for windows. I did not found any dhcp class for php. I found some clases for perl and python however I did not manage to run it on windows. Does anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: It should not drop/reset the interface until the lease is up, and should request a new lease at about ½ the lease time. As 1 minute is a short time, if the PC can not request a new lease reliably in the last ½ minute of the lease then you may be able to configure the dhcp client to start earlier. Or to hack the configuration of the dhcp client to make the lease time longer, and re-leasing still once per-minute.

Comment: When refreshing IP from dhcp on wireless connection windows breaks all current connections (like downloading something in browser). Even to my own wifi router with happens when I do ipconfig /renew. I've tested this on 4 diffrent wireless cards and 3 windows systems and one android system (4 diffrent computers). There is always break in connection when renewing wireless connection but not on wired connection (on wired ipconfig /renew does not break connections) - so I try to walk around it with this custom dhcp stuff

Comment: like I said this happens on windows (xp, 7) and android linux. I could test in on normal linux kernel however I'm trying to set up stable connection (with this 1 minute lease wifi from isp) for someone else and he uses windows so changing OS is not an option.

Comment: On android and Gnu+Linux it is done by user process not kernel, so maybe if you can to configure it, then you can install another. I will +1 the question in the hope that someone that knows will see it.